# Simple Number Theory question on Highest Common Factor (or Divisor)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Without prime factorization, show that for any natural numbers a,b, the number l=ab/hcf(a,b) is an integer.
We must use the fact that hcd(a,b) can be written as a linear combination of a and b, i.e hcf(a,b) = ua+vb for some integers u and v.

Comment: @woofy, I do *not* see how it follows immediately from Bezout's identity. I do see how it follows from the *definition* of highest common factor (or divisior): If hcf(a,b) is the highest common factor of a and b, then in particular it's a factor of b (and a, but you only need one of them), so b/hcf(a,b) is an integer, and thus, on multiplying by a, the product ab/hcf(a,b) is an integer.

Comment: @BarryCipra Perhaps to *make* this question a meaningful one, "hcf(a,b)" has to be *defined in another way*, like the smallest positive linear combination of a and b.

Comment: @GNUSupporter, I agree! In that case, perhaps the notation should be splc(a,b).... (Note, though, that the OP only mentions the fact that hcf(a,b) is *some* linear combination, without saying anything about it being the smallest.

Comment: @BarryCipra Sometimes we have to find out the true meaningful question hidden in vague words.

Comment: To the OP (Jesse):  What GNU Supporter and I are saying is that, given the usual definition of highest common factor, we don't see any need for using the fact that it's a linear combination of a and b, so there seems to be some context missing from your question.

Comment: Cheers guys, yeah I think you are right, we can just use the normal definition for the highest common factor. That was what I was confused about regarding the question.

Comment: @JesseLingard If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$gcd(a,b)=d$$

thus **by definition**:

$$\exists \ m \in \text{$\mathbb{Z}$ such that} \quad m= \frac{b}{d}$$

thus:

$$l=am=\frac{ab}{d} \in \text{$\mathbb{Z}$} \quad \square$$

Answer (score 0):

I think this is deceptive in that $l = hcf(a,b)$ is a lot more information than you need and this is akin to shooting a fly with a shotgun.

$l= hcf(a,b)$ is a factor of $a$.  That is *all* you need to know.  You do not need to know that it is the highest common factor or even that it *is* a factor of $b$ at all.

$l = hcf(a,b)$ is a factor of $a$.  Therefore $l$ divides $a$ therefore $a = l*k$ for some integer $k$.  Therefore $\frac {ab}l = \frac {l*k*b}l = k*b$.  And $kb$ is an integer because $k$ and $b$ are integers and the integers are closed under multiplication.

> We must use the fact that hcd(a,b) can be written as a linear combination of a and b, i.e hcf(a,b) = ua+vb for some integers u and v.

You most certainly do *not* need to do any such thing at all!